# How can I pass the ID of a post to a page template by clicking a url?

Tags: posts, pages, templates

I have a post gallery and I'm displaying the thumbnails in example.com/gallery. Now this thumbnails are created via posts and when you click on on eof the thumbnails, it will direct you to single.php template. It goes to display a gallery room which mimics a Gallery Exhibit created with HTML5 and CSS3. Its quite heavy to load and doesn't really have the standard web gallery feel and I want an option for users to click weather to view it in Gallery Room or  the standard grid which the native WordPress Gallery has.

Now I want, in my example.com/gallery, to have two links. One on the Gallery Room and one on the standard grid. But how can I do this? I have already created a template for the standard gallery but how can I dynamically get the ID of the post whenever the user click on the 1st link in the example.com/gallery page.

I have this in my template:

```
$post_id = 527;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
```

527 being the post ID. But of course this is not dynamic. I want to pass that ID to a url by clicking a link and will be stored to a variable which will be the value of the $post_id.

Can anyone help?

thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to pass information in a `GET` string in PHP?

Comment: yes. Can you do that in WordPress?

Comment: Yes, same as in any other PHP application, just avoiding parameter names that WordPress uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking a link from a post to a page you can concatenate the post_id to the end of the link as a GET variable.

So let's say you had a link within the WordPress loop you can easily add the post_id as a GET variable as such

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(): ?>
        <a href="http://example.com/gallery?my_gallery_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Gallery</a>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So with just the URL you would have:

```
http://example.com/gallery?my_gallery_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>
```

Comment: thanks Jenkins. So now the ID is in the URL, how can I pass that ID now in the template page?

Comment: Great!  Now you can retrieve the post_id by doing a $_GET['my_gallery_id'];

Comment: You just made a miracle Jenkins! All Good now. Thanks so much!